# Assert that a WebElement is not present using Selenium WebDriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, assertion

In tests that I write, if I want to assert a WebElement is present on the page, I can do a simple:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test Search"));
```

This will pass if it exists and it will bomb out if it does not exist.  But now I want to assert that a link does *not* exist.  I am unclear how to do this since the code above does not return a boolean.

*EDIT* This is how I came up with my own fix, I'm wondering if there's a better way out there still.

```
public static void assertLinkNotPresent (WebDriver driver, String text) throws Exception {
List<WebElement> bob = driver.findElements(By.linkText(text));
  if (bob.isEmpty() == false) {
    throw new Exception (text + " (Link is present)");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not Sure which version of selenium you are referring to, however some commands in selenium * can now do this:
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html

- assertNotSomethingSelected
- assertTextNotPresent

Etc..

Comment: Link broken now

Comment: The OPs original problem seems to indicate an exception was thrown when the element isn't present.

Answer (score 45):

It's easier to do this:

```
driver.findElements(By.linkText("myLinkText")).size() < 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems the best approach even for non-Java bindings.

Comment: This is by far the better answer to avoid having the exception thrown by findElement.

Comment: Good solution. However, this tries for `timeout` seconds to find the element. So you might want to set (and then reset) the drivers timeout. Perhaps in a method.

Answer (score 12):

I think that you can just catch `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` that will be thrown by `driver.findElement` if there's no such element:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;

....

public static void assertLinkNotPresent(WebDriver driver, String text) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(text));
        fail("Link with text <" + text + "> is present");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) { 
        /* do nothing, link is not present, assert is passed */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: nice idea. Though strange there isn't a mechanism to deal with this kind of assertion already available in Web Driver

Comment: to make this more genetic you could pass in a By.id/cssSelector etc. instead of the String Text.

Comment: While this works I don't think it is ideal. When you have the webdriver configured with an implicit wait the test will become very slow.

Comment: this is really unrecommended, it will slow down you test and can be source of hard-to-find bugs:
- if the element is not there (the most common) your test will wait for the implicit wait every time
- if the element is there but it's disappearing, the implicit wait will not be used, and your test will fail immediately, a false positive.

Comment: Due to implicit wait issue this needs to be downvoted hard.

Comment: @Dave you cant assert on an absent element without knowing its id or cssSelector. This answer addresses the question appropriately.

Comment: @sanu I believe what I was thinking was the function could take the data type `findElement` is expecting instead of a string, that way you can use this more generally. Whether it's by linkText, by ID, by cssSelector, etc.

But that was 9 years ago, who knows what I was thinking.

Answer (score 9):

There is an Class called `ExpectedConditions`:

```
  By loc = ...
  Boolean notPresent = ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(loc)).apply(getDriver());
  Assert.assertTrue(notPresent);
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me (at least in Selenium `2.53.0`). Instead I had to use the presence of **all** elements like this: `ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator)));`.

Comment: Using some latest Versions of Selenium there is now a Methode called `invisibilityOfElementLocated` for this check. Usage is straight forward: `webDriver.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(xpath("<xpath expression>")))`

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
private boolean verifyElementAbsent(String locator) throws Exception {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
        System.out.println("Element Present");
        return false;

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Element absent");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this won't work. I use Perl bindings and tried to use this approach and the problem was that the driver instance died when no element found. Not sure whether the same happens with Java.

Comment: How can you findElement using a locator for which a locator is not present since the element is not present. Doesnt make sense

Answer (score 4):

With Selenium Webdriver would be something like this:

```
assertTrue(!isElementPresent(By.linkText("Empresas en Misión")));
```

Comment: Better just `assertFalse(...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean titleTextfield = driver.findElement(By.id("widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_title")).isDisplayed();
assertFalse(titleTextfield, "Title text field present which is not expected");
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `findElements()` only returns quickly if it finds at least one element.  Otherwise it waits for the implicit wait timeout, before returning zero elements - just like `findElement()`.

To keep the speed of the test good, this example temporarily shortens the implicit wait, while waiting for the element to disappear:

```
static final int TIMEOUT = 10;

public void checkGone(String id) {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.id(id), 0));
    } finally {
        resetTimeout();
    }
}

void resetTimeout() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Still looking for a way to avoid the timeout completely though...

Answer (score 1):

You can utlilize [Arquillian Graphene](http://arquillian.org/modules/graphene-extension/) framework for this. So example for your case could be

```
Graphene.element(By.linkText(text)).isPresent().apply(driver));
```

Is also provides you bunch of nice API's for working with Ajax, fluent waits, page objects, fragments and so on. It definitely eases a Selenium based test development a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For node.js I've found the following to be effective way to wait for an element to no longer be present:

```
// variable to hold loop limit
    var limit = 5;
// variable to hold the loop count
    var tries = 0;
        var retry = driver.findElements(By.xpath(selector));
            while(retry.size > 0 && tries < limit){
                driver.sleep(timeout / 10)
                tries++;
                retry = driver.findElements(By.xpath(selector))
            }
```

Comment: You code can fall into infinite loop if element doesn't dissapear

Comment: An excellent point. Fixed that. I'm not going to add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer to the very question but perhaps an idea for the underlying task:*

When your site logic should not show a certain element, you could insert an invisible "flag" element that you check for.

```
if condition
    renderElement()
else
    renderElementNotShownFlag() // used by Selenium test
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example using Selenium "until.stalenessOf" and Jasmine assertion.
It returns true when element is no longer attached to the DOM.

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

it('should not find element', async () => {
   const waitTime = 10000;
   const el = await driver.wait( until.elementLocated(By.css('#my-id')), waitTime);
   const isRemoved = await driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(el), waitTime);

   expect(isRemoved).toBe(true);
});
```

For ref.: [Selenium:Until Doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have found best - and also to show in Allure report as fail - is to try-catch the findelement and in the catch block, set the assertTrue to false, like this:

```
    try {
        element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test Search"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        assertTrue(false, "Test Search link was not displayed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best approach for me

```
public boolean isElementVisible(WebElement element) {
    try { return element.isDisplayed(); } catch (Exception ignored) { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a JavaScript (with TypeScript support) implementation I came up with something, not very pretty, that works:

```
  async elementNotExistsByCss(cssSelector: string, timeout=100) {
    try {
      // Assume that at this time the element should be on page
      await this.getFieldByCss(cssSelector, timeout);
      // Throw custom error if element s found
      throw new Error("Element found");
    } catch (e) {
      // If element is not found then we silently catch the error
      if (!(e instanceof TimeoutError)) {
        throw e;
      }
      // If other errors appear from Selenium it will be thrown
    }
  }
```

P.S: I am using *"selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.1"*

Answer (score -1):

findElement will check the html source and will return true even if the element is not displayed. To check whether an element is displayed or not use -

```
private boolean verifyElementAbsent(String locator) throws Exception {

        boolean visible = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).isDisplayed();
        boolean result = !visible;
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For appium 1.6.0 and above

```
    WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='your button']"))));
    button.click();

    Assert.assertTrue(!button.isDisplayed());
```

Comment: better directly `assertFalse(...)`