# How to judge whether an element does not exist?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to excute case when an element doesn't exist, but it throws an exception..if I use try catch, I'll need to wait the implicitlyWait time . is there any other better method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283310/assert-that-a-webelement-is-not-present

Comment: Please add the code or use tags. This will help other what you have tried.

Comment: Does not exist = in the DOM or on the screen? Different things.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear from your question, but if you want to run a test case when an element is not present, then use `findElements` instead of `findElement`.

Something like:

```
driver.findElements(//your criteria)
```

Even though your element is not exists, it doesn't throw the error. Instead it returns the empty list. Then you can use `size` method to check!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an element is displayed on the page:
`driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).isDisplayed();`

Comment: If foo object does not exists, then it will throw an Exception. So better check with "findelements" and compare its list size.

Comment: That's true, but it can be solved with asking the IDE to surround it with the Try/Catch block. I think it is more proper then checking its size.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the complete code:

```
Integer x=driver.findElements(By.id("XYZ")).size();
if(x>0)
    System.out.println("Element exists");
else
    System.out.println("Element does not exist");
```