# Appium/Selenium - assert that element declared as field is NOT displayed

Tags: java, selenium, junit, appium

I declare a button as field in following fashion:

```
@AndroidFindBy(name = "Schedule")
private WebElement calendarButton;
```

... and later I make sure it's NOT displayed because the app is in some special mode.

```
Assert.assertFalse(this.calendarButton.isDisplayed());
```

It gives me **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException**, but the test is failed. Any ideas how can I make such assertion?

The thing I don't want to define By condition a few times in the code, so using property is handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking I came up with following solution:

```
public static boolean elementIsPresent(AndroidElement element) {
    try {
        element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I use this method in following way:

```
Assert.assertFalse(elementIsPresent(this.calendarButton));
```

I was inspired by one of the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283310/assert-that-a-webelement-is-not-present-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java).

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and accept this answer so that the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: What if element supposed to appear after a few seconds. I mean don't you want to use fluent wait. If the element doesn't appear in few expected seconds then return false.